# Arithmetic in complex numbers isn't working properly

Tags: c, math, complex-numbers

The context is simply a function that solves input quadratic equations. Here's the section of the code which malfunctions:

```
case NEGATIVE:
        printf("\n\n beforehand sqrt(discriminant) is %f%+fi",creal(csqrt(eqn->discriminant)), cimag(csqrt(eqn->discriminant)));
        eqn->complex_root = (-(eqn->b)+csqrt(eqn->discriminant))/(2*eqn->a);
        printf("\n\n result after full formula is %f%+fi", creal(eqn->complex_root),cimag(eqn->complex_root));
        break;
```

And the output text I get with `x^2+5 = 0` as the trial equation. The middle three lines are debugging text, where type simply refers to what kind of solutions the program should expect for the quadratic (0 means 2 complex solutions of course):

```
Please enter the coefficients of the quadratic separated by spaces: 1 0 5

The coefficients entered are a=1, b=0 and c=5.

TYPE RETURNED: 0


beforehand sqrt(discriminant) is 0.000000+4.472136i

result after full formula is 0.000000+0.000000i


The equation defined by 1x^2 +0x +5=0 has two complex solutions, x = 0+0i and x = 0-0i.
```

I simply have no idea why the results reduce to 0. What's going on?

Comment: Could you show your function `creal`, `cimag` and `csqrt`?

Comment: They're in <complex.h>

Comment: It's ok, I found out the issue.. It turns out you need to declare the variable as having a complex value before it can be assigned them properly. I had a float rather than float _Complex. Sorry for wasting people's time!

Comment: @FireGarden  Post and accept you own answer.  This will save additional people's time.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to assign the variable holding these values as complex. i.e. used float instead of float _Complex.